# Importing Java Library JAR into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import, jar

I'm currently trying to implement a browser with pipelining feature in it. The problem is in order to code the HTTP pipeline, i need the support of a library. I tried to import it to my workspace by using Project - > properties -> Java build path ->addJar. And I was able to add it successfully. But now my problem is, even though it is added to my workspace it doesnt let me run this code. It gives me errors as if I have not imported the library:

```
package com.test.download;
import java.util.Collections;
import org.factor45.*;
    public class Example {

        // Execute the request
        HttpRequestFuture<String> future = client.execute("hotpotato.factor45.org", 80, request,
                                                          new BodyAsStringProcessor());
        future.addListener(new HttpRequestFutureListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(HttpRequestFuture<String> future) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(future);
                if (future.isSuccessfulResponse()) {
                    System.out.println(future.getProcessedResult());
                }
                client.terminate();
            }
        });
    }
```

This is available in the same website which provided me the library for the above code. ["Here"](http://www.zetascope.com/url/a50314975d8d1e792b6e447a8c49fed9/content) is the website for your reference. Also you can find the JAR file inside this website.

Please help me to figure out the problem. If you solve this you are a life saver! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put the jar in the /libs folder, and then add it to the build path.

Comment: Make a folder named libs in your project root and copy and paste library file in to it.

Comment: @RaghavSood: I already tried that, but doesnt make anydifference

Comment: can it be something else which that is bothering? coz as I mentioned, I already did import the library into my project successfully, even though it doesnt support the above mentioned code.

Comment: Are you sure the library is compatible with Android?

Comment: @RaghavSood: its built for android.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Properties >> Java Build Path >> Libraries >> Add External JARs... Then select the library